# How to create a simple WPF UserControl button with custom enabled/disabled images?

Tags: wpf, image, user-controls, button

I am a bit new to WPF and XAML, just learning now.

I found a quick-n-dirty code by some previous developer:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border Name="buttonBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.0" />
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.8" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Effect">                   
                         <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.8" Direction="135"  
                             ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="1" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                   <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>            
                   <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.0"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>     

            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Basically it is just a template for a button with a basic mouseover effect and the image for disabled state bound to Tag (seems an ugly solution).

I want to create a custom button which works pretty the same, but I want to expose two custom properties: NormalImage and DisabledImage. Those properties should be of type string not Uri. I want to use the path to image just "apply.png" and not "pack://application:,,,/Resources/Apply.png". 
I guess, to have such custom properties I need a UserControl with dependency properties?

Basically, I want to use the button as follows:

```
<MyImageButton NormalImage="apply.png" DisabledImage="apply_disabled.png"/>
```

Maybe NormalImage/DisabledImage will be bound to something later but that's unlikely.

I could not find any example which implements such a basic button with custom properties, there are only some fancy buttons and controls online. Maybe I am just using incorrect keywords...

**Could anyone point me to the right article or throw some simple piece of code to play with?**

WPF is so complicated for beginners, sometimes it just does not work as expected, for example I still do not understand why I can add Trigger tag to ControlTemplate, but I cannot add Trigger tag straight to UserControl...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could also use a `UserControl` which is a bit messy since your button will be encapsulated, would look something like this:

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.ImageButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Button Name="button" Click="button_Click" Width="50" Height="50">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="buttonBorder">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.0" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Border.Child>
                        <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding NormalImage}"/>
                    </Border.Child>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.8" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.8" Direction="135"  
                             ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="1" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding DisabledImage}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.0"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ImageButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
    {
        public ImageSource DisabledImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(DisabledImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisabledImageProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisabledImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        public ImageSource NormalImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(NormalImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NormalImageProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("NormalImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public event RoutedEventHandler Click;

        public ImageButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Click != null)
            {
                Click(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
        <local:ImageButton x:Name="imgbutton"
                           NormalImage="C:/1.png"
                           DisabledImage="C:/2.png"
                           Click="ImgButton_Click"/>
```

(Note that the current namespace is `Test`, you might want to change that; Also i set a fixed size on the internal button, which you might want to remove, just make sure to set the size somewhere since i think it will not use any space at all if you don't.)

Comment: Thanks, I used Style instead of ControlTemplate and added some OnXImagePropertyChanged handlers to your ImageSource code and finally it works. Actually I now can add some default path property for the buttons image folder.

Comment: @JustAMartin How could you handle the new image source changed event, to set new value to your control?

Comment: @Dia  I dig out our old code and created a Gist. It might have some errors because I had to remove some project specific pieces of code, but I think it should be usable as an example. https://gist.github.com/progmars/9d51e50fa03042264a83941e4f1e99c5

Answer (score 2):

This is how I see it:

1) Create your `MyImageButton` class which should inherit regular `Button` and include two dependency properties - `NormalImage` and `DisabledImage`. These properties should be of `ImageSource` type. See here how to define dependency properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx#back_dependency_properties

2) Change your style to be a style for `MyImageButton`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:MyImageButton}">
```

3) Change `ImageBrush` in your style for both enabled and disabled mode to use `TemplateBinding`. This is how it should be for enabled mode:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{TemplateBinding NormalImage}"  />
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. But can I have NormalImage/DisabledImage as plain strings to simplify usage of MyImageButton?

Comment: I'm not sure wether it will work or not. Also it will simplify usage only from code-behind (not from XAML) because in XAML string will be converted to `ImageSource` transparently. Also using `ImageSource` seems to be aligned with WPF - strings are not used for such properties in WPF.

Comment: The reason why I would like to use strings is to avoid using the full path everywhere, so I can just put "enabledimage.png" instead of "pack://application:,,,/Resources/enabledimage.png", and WPF does not prepend pack://application automatically for me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [greyableimage.codeplex.com](http://greyableimage.codeplex.com/)

This can be used in place of a regular image control on buttons, menus, toolbars etc. It auto-generates a "greyed-out" version of the content that will be displayed when the parent control is disabled.